# checking number of td tags in a dynamic table and divide them into two equal tr tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The question title might seems ambiguous but I will try to explain in detail over here.

So I am generating a dynamic table based on the JSON data. Inside the table I have few  tags and in one of the  tag I am further populating table data enclosed in  tags. Number of tables inside the td tag might varies but the maximum number of tables are 4. Here is the rough HTML markup which is generated after the table is populated.

Current mark up

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Expected mark up

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

As you can see in the third  tag I have 4  tag which contains individual tables. What I am trying to achieve if the number of  tags in the third  row is greater than 2 then I should create another  tag below that and divide the 4  tags (which contains tables) into 2  tags (with 2  tags each).

Since the tables are generated dynamically I don't have a predefined HTML mark up.

This is my relevant JS function

drawRunningDailyDoublesTables: function (events, table) {

```
        var indexes = $(table).data('BetTableData').eventIndexes;
        table.innerHTML = '';

        // Drawing STAB / NSW product selection
        betTable.drawBetTypeProductSelection(table);

        // Error space
        betTable.drawErrorSpace(table);

        var trForTables = $('<tr/>')
            .appendTo(table);

        // Drawing tables for doubles
        $.each(indexes, function(j, index) {
            var betTableData = new BetTableData();
            betTableData.setMarketId(events[index].markets[0].id);

            var doubleTable = $('<table/>')
                .data('BetTableData', betTableData);

            // Names and info of races
            betTable.drawHeaderForDoubles(doubleTable, events[index], 3);

            // Horse selections
            betTable.drawSelectionsForRunningDoubles(table, doubleTable, events[index], j+1);

            // here I am generating the td tag with tables as mentioned in the question. It could be 2,3 or 4 depending on the different situation.
            $('<td style="vertical-align: top;"/>')
                .appendTo(trForTables)
                .append(doubleTable)

            // Footer
            createFooterRowForRunningDoubles("white", 2, table, doubleTable, j+1);
        });

        // draw button for betting
        betTable.drawExoticBetBtnForDoubles(table);
        betTable.selectDefaultRadioProduct(table);
    },
```

Comment: Create a JSFiddle to assist the answerer isolating the affected code + post a Before: and After: (you have only before in your question) of what the markup will look like after answerers code is applied,

Comment: @JFit I have updated my question with before and after markup. I am not sure on how to recreate the scenario on Fiddle since there is nothing hardcore in my code. Everything is generated dynamically,

Comment: so you want  </tr><tr> after every 2 inner-tables?

Comment: @JFit thats right. The moment it finds there are 4 tables in the third tr tag. It divides them into two tr tags with 2 td (which contains tables) each.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MXGBu/2/

```
var thirdRow = $('table:first>tbody>tr:nth-child(3)');

var tablesInThird = thirdRow.find('table');


if(tablesInThird.length === 4)
{
 thirdRow.after('<tr class="arse"></tr>');//creates a new tr after 3rd row
 tablesInThird.eq(2).parent().appendTo($('tr.arse')); //adds 3rd table
 tablesInThird = thirdRow.find('table');
 tablesInThird.eq(2).parent().appendTo($('tr.arse')); //adds 4th table
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working as an standalone snippet on Fiddle. However, I am clueless how do I integrate it to my function mention above.

Comment: you are loading it dynamically right? you'll need to put it in AFTER the content is loaded, i.e. on a complete/success/ function.

Comment: Once the dynamic content is loaded into the DOM. Wouldn't it be useless to manipulate the data/table afterwards? I somehow need to manipulate this piece of code $('<td style="vertical-align: top;"/>') .appendTo(trForTables) .append(doubleTable). Currently It returns 4 td tables (for this scenario) and then I am appending this onto one tr tag as defined in the function above. Would it be possible to divide the 4 td tables into group of 2 here itself and then append the 2 td groups to the tr tag as defined in the function. Also this should be done before the content is loaded into the DOM?

Comment: Perhaps it could be done by CSS or setting some width property onto the td element itself and move 3rd and 4th td tables on the next row?

Comment: Not really sure how that would be possible without jquery to manipulate the dom.. the function you are using is loading elements into the dom but i was under the impression that the format of the markup was determined by the items being added.. if thats not the case then you can manipulate beforehand either.

Comment: yes the format of the markup is determined by the number of items based on the number of table returned. There are only 2 cases. 1) There are only 2 tables returned in the third tr tag which seems to be working fine and I don't need to worry about displaying it. 2) Four tables are returned and I cant show all of them at once on the webpage because of width issue. Thus I wanted to show into 2x2 columns. I am back to square one and I don't have an idea how to tackle this issue. Thank you for looking at the problem anyway. Cheers